# disk spac problem

Tags: xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. I have partitioned the disk so that I have
1) a partition for home directories
2) a partition for all multimedia stuff
3) a partition for the system, mounted as /

My problem is that the partion for / is 20gb and is apparently 98% used. That's scare me.

Well xubuntu fit on a CD, how can be possible that I have 20Gb used? I've not installed anything crazy (I have tools like libreoffice and auctex, that's baiscally all)
I mean, I have the same program installed I always had (and I never had problem of disk space)

So, I suspect that I have some "trash" somewhere, I tryed by using du command but I'm not able to do anything good with that.

Is there any standard/easy way to Clean my filesystem?

Comment: How did you measure disk space usage? What does `du / | sort -n | tail -20` says? (be ready this may take some time to finish).

Comment: I use df for checking filesystems and du for specific diractories. Du says for instance that I have plenty of stuff in /usr but I don't know what of such stuff I can erase

Comment: My hope is that there is some "cache" material or similar that can be cleaned out in some standard way

Comment: Did you run the command above? It should display 20 largest files on your system. How did you run `df`? I'm asking this to make sure you counted the correct bytes. As for the "cache", there's `/tmp` directory, where programs usually save their temporary files. Those are save to delete. But I would still try running the above to make sure you don't have some huge log file generated by some program.

Comment: I get all the multimedia directories (which I stored in a dedicated partition, which is b.t.w.  far to being full) plus a lot of mistakes "du: impossibile accedere a '/proc/5041/task/5041/fd/4': File o directory non esistente" which translated in english sounds " impossible to accesss [...] file or directory does not exist"

Comment: Re' errors: yes, that would be normal, since `/proc` filesystem isn't really a filesystem, it's information about the operating system exposed as if it ware files and directories. Also see this question for information on how to exclude mounted filesystems from `du` report: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287012/linux-du-command-without-traversing-mounted-file-systems